# как преобразовать строку в математическое выражение

Tags: javascript

например есть строка sin(x^2)  как преобразовать её в Math.sin(pow(x,2))

Answer (score 4):

Есть библиотека [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/)

В ней можно выполнять выражения:

```
math.eval('sqrt(3^2 + 4^2)')            // 5
math.eval('sqrt(-4)')                   // 2i
math.eval('2 inch to cm')               // 5.08 cm
math.eval('cos(45 deg)')                // 0.7071067811865476
```

[Песочница где можно попробовать](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/PdYYLK?editors=0010)